# Why select doesn't work in ExtJS (Ext.selection.Model)

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a strange problem.

In my code, I've this lines :

```
var theId = operation.records[0].get('id');
console.log("theId: " + theId); // print 4 in firebug
var index = gridStore.find('id', theId);
console.log("index: " + index); // print 3 in firebug

if (index != -1) {
    gridPanel.getSelectionModel().select(index);
}
```

The selection doesn't work !

Now, if I change :

```
var theId = operation.records[0].get('id');
```

to

```
var theId = 4;
```

... the selection works

and :

```
console.log("theId: " + theId);
```

print 4 in firebug

```
console.log("index: " + index);
```

print 3 in firebug

Why ? **the content of theId is always 4 and the content of index is always 3 !!!**

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Jean-Michel

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to say that I have a selectionchange event on my grid in the controller :

```
gridSelectionChange: function(grid, records) {
    console.log('gridSelectionChange');

    if (records[0]) {
        this.getAuthorForm().getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);
    }
},
```

If I remove this, all works fine... but my bind formpanel is not updated. So I need it.

Jean-Michel

Comment: Can paste the full code to pastebin or a gist? It would be good to see the grid configuration, and where you are executing this code. I don't see how this function could have an effect on the select method but maybe something in the config has.